# Dúvida em atribuição via desestruturação - Javascript

Tags: javascript, lógica

Não consegui compreender o seguinte código:

```
//Esse array vai modificar o DOM com o seu conteúdo
const elementos = [             
    { tag: 'p', texto: 'Frase 1' }, // indice 0
    { tag: 'div', texto: 'Frase 2' }, // indice 1
    { tag: 'section', texto: 'Frase 3' }, // indice 2
    { tag: 'footer', texto: 'Frase 4' } // indice 3
];

const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const div = document.createElement('div');

for (let i = 0; i < elementos.length; i++) {
    const { tag, texto } = elementos[i]; 
    const elemento = document.createElement(tag);
    const noTexto = document.createTextNode(texto);
    elemento.appendChild(noTexto);
    div.appendChild(elemento);
    console.log(elementos[i]);
}
container.appendChild(div);
```

O código está funcionando normalmente, no caso, a minha dúvida é: Por que na hora de atribuir, não é necessário colocar os colchetes? Ex: `[{tag, texto}] = elementos[i];`

Comment: Por que precisaría? Isso é uma sintaxe criada especificamente para desestruturação, poderia ser qualquer coisa. Mas pense assim, o colchete já está desreferenciando do outro lado ;)

Comment: Porque, quando vi atribuição via desestruturação, para pegar um object dentro do array, eu vi que precisava usar os colchetes. 
Ex: 
const exem = [ 'bla', 'bla', {nome: 'tal'}];

const [, , {nome}] = exem;

Comment: No código da pergunta você não está desestruturando o objeto de dentro da array, já "retirou" da array quando acessou elemento[i]

Comment: Entendi. Valeu, cara, você removeu uma pulga detrás da minha orelha! Eu não segui em frente nos estudos, porque não tinha entendido isso, agora irei continuar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caso você fizesse o que você gostaria, ele tentaria procurar um 1 posição no vetor que está fazendo o destructure, mas como está em um for e já selecionou a posição, a única maneira de dar certo essa sintaxe seria em um caso como esse:

```js
const elementos = [             
    { tag: 'p', texto: 'Frase 1' },
    { tag: 'div', texto: 'Frase 2' },
    { tag: 'section', texto: 'Frase 3' },
    { tag: 'footer', texto: 'Frase 4' }
]
const [{ tag, texto }] = elementos
```

Então apenas daria certo a forma como você queria nesse caso:

```js
const elementos = [
    [{ tag: 'p', texto: 'Frase 1' }],
    [{ tag: 'div', texto: 'Frase 2' }],
    [{ tag: 'section', texto: 'Frase 3' }],
    [{ tag: 'footer', texto: 'Frase 4' }]
]
const [{ tag, texto }] = elementos[0]
```

Ou seja, precisaria colocar outro vetor dentro do vetor, assim se tornando uma matriz.
Uma observação caso estivesse usando TypeScript teria dado um erro que para resolver você poderia utilizar `// @ts-ignore` na linha anterior ou usar a seguinte sintaxe:

```js
const elementos = [             
    { tag: 'p', texto: 'Frase 1' },
    { tag: 'div', texto: 'Frase 2' },
    { tag: 'section', texto: 'Frase 3' },
    { tag: 'footer', texto: 'Frase 4' }
]
// forma longa
const [indice1] = elementos
const { tag, texto } = indice1
// forma curta (foi a forma como foi feita na pergunta)
const { tag, texto } = elementos[0]
```

Comment: Resumindo, não preciso usar os colchetes por causa do for, não é?

Comment: Bom sim e por causa que você não está numa matriz para acessar daquela forma no for.

Comment: Valeu, cara. Consegui compreender. Agora posso continuar estudando

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente, o que vc está fazendo é retirar as propriedades internas do array, desestruturando  os valor presente dentro do array em objetos.

Por estar dentro de um for, é preciso referenciar o indice do item para que os valores sejam atribuídos corretamente.

Comment: Eu entendi o que é desestruturação e o que ela faz, só não tinha entendido o porque de quando eu fui pegar os valores {tag, texto} = elementos[i], eu n precisei coloca-los dentro de colchetes assim [{tag, texto}] = elementos[i]. Mas o amigo acima já me explicou que é por causa do for

Comment: Perfeito! Outro modo de se fazer isso, muito mais elegante e funcional, é através do uso do forEach, que navega pelos indices do array de forma Intrínseca sem a necessidade explicita de mapear o index do array. Você pode saber mais sobre este modo através deste link https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: o forEach ainda irei estudar!